# Change the data.frame's name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change my code's data.frame.s name. But i have problem to work it.

```
A<-function(x){
data.frame(max(x),min(x))
 }
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1)
A(x)
names(A(x))
names(A(x))<-c("max","min")
```

It always appear  Error in names(A(x)) <- c("max", "min") : could not find function "A<-" How could i change the A(x)'s names?

Comment: You could use `setNames()` instead `df <- setNames(A(x), c("max", "min"))`

Comment: you could change your functions body to be `data.frame(max = max(x), min = min(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `names()` function directly on the data frame.  To do this, first assign your data frame to a variable, then change the column names.

```
df <- A(x)
names(df) <- c("max","min")

> df
  max min
1   5   1
```